# Creation of a partitioned external table with hive: no data available

Tags: hive, hdfs, external, partition

I have the following file on HDFS:
[image]

I create the structure of the **external table** in Hive:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE google_analytics(
  `session` INT)
PARTITIONED BY (date_string string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION '/flumania/google_analytics';

ALTER TABLE google_analytics ADD PARTITION (date_string = '2016-09-06') LOCATION '/flumania/google_analytics';
```

After that, the table structure is created in Hive but I cannot see any data:
[image]

Since it's an external table, data insertion should be done automatically, right?

Comment: You have to use either **insert overwrite** or **insert into** to insert data into partition table

Comment: I think not because it is an external table.

Comment: table ddl should have two columns right.

Comment: Your Alter command is not correct. Location should be `/flumania/google_analytics/date_string=2016-09-06`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem was with the alter table command. The code below solved my problem:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE google_analytics(
  `session` INT)
PARTITIONED BY (date_string string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION '/flumania/google_analytics/';

ALTER TABLE google_analytics ADD PARTITION (date_string = '2016-09-06');
```

After these two steps, if you have a date_string=2016-09-06 subfolder with a csv file corresponding to the structure of the table, **data will be automatically loaded** and you can already use select queries to see the data.

Solved!

Answer (score 1):

your file should be in this sequence.

int,string

here you file contents are in below sequence

string, int

change your file to below.

86,"2016-08-20"
78,"2016-08-21"

It should work.
Also it is not recommended to use keywords as column names (date);

Comment: I have reversed the order of the columns and renamed the date field. Still no data available. Any other idea?